# Implement "remember me" with facebook login in Symfony2

Tags: facebook, symfony

I have a site where users can log in with 2 kind of credentials:

1. Their email/password combination
2. Through facebook, by clicking the "login with facebook" button

I have successfully implemented the remember me functionality for the first case, but I have no clue how to start on the second one. I'm using FOSFacebookBundle, but looking through its docs, I don't see remember me mentioned at all.

How do I implement remember me with facebook login?

Answer (score 0):

Simply there are route for security check (check_path)

```
        fos_facebook:
            remember_me: true
            login_path: /login
            check_path: _security_check_facebook
```

And auth url inside javascript

```
    <script>var authurl = '{{ path('_security_check_facebook', {'_remember_me': 1}) }}';</script>
```

so add _remember_me and it will work.